# Finding File Size in javascritpt

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the file size before upload

i use the code **file[0].size** but it is not working IE

Please help me to get the file size in IE To

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

That works in IE10. But, since the `size` property of `File` objects is HTML5 specific, there's no chance you can do that with pure Javascript in IE9 and older. Yes, that sucks.

You'll have to rely on some Flash solutions or something like that.

Comment: No prob, sorry for not being of any help. By the way, use double asterisks to render something bold here on StackExchange, like `**something bold**` => **something bold**.

Comment: @Stano What should that (bad) fiddle prove or do?

Comment: @MaxArt That (good) fiddle is only example and simply proves that filesize counting doesn't work in Explorer. Didn't test it carefully in Explorer and so you are right, it was overcomplicated and that Browser Checking code was redundant. So the simplified fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9RBes/3/

Comment: @Stano I guess OP already figured that out. The fiddle is indeed bad because of the UA string sniffing instead of the feature check.

Comment: Oh yeah, Max you're right, UA string is not reliable checking. But that [3rd fiddle above](http://jsfiddle.net/9RBes/3/) i guess is already ok, isn't it? Please can you explain me, what does it mean OP ? Operator? Or what? Is it some English internet slang?

Comment: @Stano OP = Original Poster. krishnaraj in this case. You'll often find this acronym in forums, message boards and this sort of things. The third version of the fiddle is ok.

Comment: @MaxArt So this is new to me. Thanks for the explanation and have a good day :-)